# Using Pointer in GetProcessMemoryInfo()

Tags: java, winapi, jna

There is my code:

```
    import com.sun.jna.Native;
        PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmem = new PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS();
        boolean success = PSAPI.GetProcessMemoryInfo(kernel32.GetCurrentProcess(), pmem, pmem.size());
                        if (!success){
                                int err=Native.getLastError();
                    System.out.println("GetProcessMemoryInfo failed:" + err);
        }
```

Structure is PSAPI-class:

```
public static class PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS extends Structure {
    public int cb;
    public int PageFaultCount;
    public int PeakWorkingSetSize;
    public int WorkingSetSize;
    public int QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
    public int QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    public int QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
    public int QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    public int PagefileUsage;
    public int PeakPagefileUsage;

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Declaration in PSAPI-class:

```
boolean GetProcessMemoryInfo(Pointer process, int pmem, int cb);
```

Is this code correct?

**GetProcessMemoryInfo()** function needs pointer to **pmem** variable, but I don't know how to realize this pointer in Java: `PSAPI.GetProcessMemoryInfo(kernel32.GetCurrentProcess(), pmem, pmem.size());`

I hope your help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using JNA. The tag is added.

Comment: `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmem = new PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS();` and redefine your method to take that type as its second parameter.

Comment: The post is updated. The structure in PSAPI-class is added. Is it right? I got an error ([screenshot](http://s12.postimg.org/tpp05egul/crerror.jpg))

Comment: Don't return `null` in `getFieldOrder()`.  That will surely trigger an exception.  You need to return a list of the structure's field names, in order.  E.g. `Arrays.asList(new String[] { "cb", "PageFaultCount", ...})`.